# How to manipulate Stored Procedures returning multiple result sets using Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, ado.net, entity-framework-6

We want to migrate existing code base of an application from ADO.NET to Entity Framework for data access. We are supposed to use legacy stored procedures only and the database is managed by the another team.

Currently we are facing an issue working with legacy SPs returning multiple result sets, as to convert all the result sets to desired types. For instance, say a stored procedure returns set of patients and physicians, then we want to convert the two result sets into `List<Patient>` and `List<Physician>`.

There are also instances where SPs are returning 4-5 result sets and we only want specific result sets like result set 2 or 3 or both of 4 and 5.

By default, if we use Database First approach, the metadata only creates complex type for First result (in this example case, it would create complex type for Patients result set). There is also `ObjectContext` API which uses the `IObjectContextAdapter` interface
(https://forums.asp.net/t/2013630.aspx?EF+6+code+first+getting+multiple+resultsets+from+stroed+procedure+)

Also looked at ways of writing wrapper code using following links and must say it really helps
https://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-6-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedures

https://www.trycatchfail.com/2015/06/03/returning-multiple-result-sets-from-a-stored-procedure-using-entity-framework-6/

What would be the best approach to tackle these scenarios? Should we continue exploring Entity Framework? Are there APIs or Nuget packages available which we could utilise?